# Why isn't the MobileFirst application store app showing my MobileFirst app icon

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, win-universal-app

I have a MobileFirst 7.1 Windows Tablet application.  When I view my list of available applications in the web page version of MobileFirst application center, I see the correct icon for each Windows Tablet application.

If I download and install the MobileFirst app store "app" onto my Windows Tablet device, when I login to the MobileFirst server and list the available and "favorite" applications, I see the correct icon for each app in the list.

**But when I drill into a particular application to install it onto my Tablet, the default "compass" icon for MobileFirst shows, not the app-specific icon for each application.**

I have created my apps to contain a logo.png, smalllogo.png and storelogo.png and included those in my jsproj file. When I install the application on my Windows Tablet device, all of the icons do show correctly for that app.

What do I need to do to get the correct icon to display in the MobileFirst Windows Tablet App Store app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default image is Appcenter_logo.png and that is the compass icon. If you need to customize the same then take the project IBMApplicationCenterWindowsStore from ApplicationCenter/installer folder into to visual studio and then replace this file and then build and use this app. Thanks

Comment: This is for the ApplicationCenter app itself right?  Is there a way I can get an image specific to each app within the ApplicationCenter app?  I'm expecting for each of my different apps to show it's specific icon.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically include the image try modifying AppDetailsPage.xaml.cs.

REST API: http://<appcenter_server_host>:<port>/applicationcenter/service/icons/application/storage/{id}

**Example:**
http://<appcenter_server_host>:<port>/applicationcenter/service/icons/application/storage/1

Hope this helps